# Necesito abrir la cámara delantera

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy una chica que está empezando en esto de la programación y la verdad que estoy un poco perdida y me he quedado estancada en la aplicación. Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de cámara personalizada para android para hacerse selfie.

Actualmente cuando abro la aplicación se me abre la cámara trasera y necesito que se abra la cámara delantera. Cree la cámara personalizada con un `textureView`. En Manifest puse los permisos de la cámara y el de `write_External_Storage` He intentado mucha cosas pero la verdad que no lo llego a conseguir. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceré muchísimo. Ya que estoy en un proyecto muy importante para mi

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATION=new SparseIntArray();


    static {
        ORIENTATION.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
        ORIENTATION.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
        ORIENTATION.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
        ORIENTATION.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
            }

    private String cameraId;
    CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
    CaptureRequest captureRequest;
    CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;

    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    Handler mBackgroudHabdler;
    HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;



   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textureView=(TextureView)findViewById(R.id.texture);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    takePicture();
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==101){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lo siento, la camara necesita permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // finish();
            }
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener=new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {



        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            try {
                openCamera();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
   private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback= new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice=camera;
           try {
               createCameraPreview();
           } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
       }

       @Override
       public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
           cameraDevice.close();
           cameraDevice=  null;

       }
   };

    private void createCameraPreview() throws CameraAccessException {

        SurfaceTexture texture=textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface=new Surface(texture);

        captureRequestBuilder=cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                if(cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                cameraCaptureSession=session;
                try {
                    updatePreview();
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cambiar configuración", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        },null);
    }

    private void updatePreview() throws CameraAccessException {

        if(cameraDevice==null){
            return;
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroudHabdler);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void openCamera() throws CameraAccessException {

        CameraManager manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        cameraId=manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

        CameraCharacteristics characteristics=manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        StreamConfigurationMap map=characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        imageDimension=map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
            return;
        }

        manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);




    }

    private void takePicture() {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView.isAvailable()){

            try {
                openCamera();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread=new HandlerThread("Camara background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroudHabdler=new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        try {
            stopBackgroundThread();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onPause();

    }

    protected void stopBackgroundThread() throws InterruptedException {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread=null;
        mBackgroudHabdler=null;

    }
}
```

Un cordial saludo

Comment: Hola @Estefania, en el método openCamara(), estas tomando el primer dispositivo dado por la función "getCamaraIdList()".  cameraId=manager.getCameraIdList()[0]; //Esa es la camara principal seguramente cameraId=manager.getCameraIdList()[1]; the dará el id de la camara secundaria.

Comment: siiiii me funcionó =) muchas gracias Alexmaister

Comment: @EstefaniadelaOsa lo ideal es obtener el id en base a sus características ya que en algunos dispositivos probablemente no sea "1" el id de la cámara frontal, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La mayoría de la ocasiones el id de la camara frontal es el "1" pero te sugiero obtener este valor en base a sus características:

### Obtener id de camara frontal usando Camera2:

para este objetivo puedes usar el método:

```
   private String getIdFrontalCamera () {
        try {
            CameraManager manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            for(String id : manager.getCameraIdList()){
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);
                //Seek frontal camera.
                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Camara frontal id " + id);
                    return id;
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "0";
    }
```

de esta forma usarías el método para obtener el id de la cámara frontal:

```
 cameraId = getIdFrontalCamera(); //manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
```

este sería el cambio en tu código:

```
  private void openCamera() throws CameraAccessException {

        CameraManager manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        cameraId = getIdFrontalCamera();

        CameraCharacteristics characteristics=manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        StreamConfigurationMap map=characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        imageDimension=map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
            return;
        }

        manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

    }
```